# Different messages are merging under ByteBuf Object while reading it from Netty library through TCP

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I have an application which processes messages which are of 3 different formats, I am using `Netty client` to receive messages over **TCP listener**.
So the issue I am facing in that is for receiving messages over `TCP`, I have to use **ByteBuf** in my Decoder class, hence messages are concatenating one after the other and I m not able to split them.
I searched over Internet and, I found we can use **LineBasedFrameDecoder**, **DelimeterBasedFrameDecoder** or **FixedLengthFieldDecoder** to resolve this, but the issue is in my message I don't have any fixed size, also I cannot use LineBasedFrameDecoder because LineBasedFrameDecoder splits the messages on the basis of new line i.e '\n' or '\r' and in my messages there can be new lines as well so LineBasedFrameDecoder will not work in this scenario as it will give the partial or half message, also I don't have any specific delimiter from which my messages ends and I can't use DelimeterBasedFrameDecoder

Please suggest me some approach to resolve this problem.
Also, Is there anything I can add to my pipeline for TCP so that my ByteBuf Object will not contain the concatenation of messages and for every decode method call I will have a single message so that I can parse them easily, just like in cases of UDP as they receive the Datagram packets for every single message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: TCP is basically just a stream of bytes without any beginnings or ends or delimiters other than what the application-level protocol adds. If the application-level protocol have neither a fixed message size, message identifier which denotes a size, a size field in general, or a fixed and well-defined delimiter, then you need to update the protocol to have one of those.

Comment: oh, so for this I have to change my message formats right? is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: A message needs to have a fixed size (can be fixed for all messages, the size could be part of a message header, or could be derived from a message type), or a well-defined "end" marker. Otherwise there's really no way to tell when one message ends and the next begins.

Comment: Also note that being a streaming protocol, when you receive message over TCP you could receive more than a single message, or only a partial message. You need to be able to handle both these cases.